# enabling multi touch... need help with storing the 2nd touch

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, touch

need to be able to store 2 touches, how I go about this i how no idea...

this is how I'm doing a single touch

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

/////checks whether the screen has been touched and stores its location and converts the coordinates to be avaible for use////
UITouch* myTouch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint locationLeft = [myTouch locationInView: [myTouch view]];
locationLeft = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:locationLeft];
```

how would I be able to store the 2nd touch?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ccTouchBegan` (notice the singular 'touch' instead of 'touches') when you need to handle multi-touches. (IMO people should just ditch the ccTouchesBegan/Moved/Ended and just use ccTouchBegan/Moved/Ended).

Each of ccTouchBegan/Moved/Ended is called for each touch which mean you can easily differentiate between multiple touches. Example:

```
- (void)registerWithTouchDispatcher {
   [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:1 swallowsTouches:YES]; 
}

- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   if (self.firstTouch == nil) {
      // we got the first touch
      self.firstTouch = touch;
   }
   else if (self.secondTouch == nil) {
      // we got the second touch
      self.secondTouch = touch;
   }
   // return YES to consume the touch (otherwise it'll cascade down the layers)
   return YES;
}

- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   if (touch == self.firstTouch) {
      // we got the first touch
      // do stuff
   }
   else if (touch == self.secondTouch) {
      // we got the second touch
      // do stuff
   }
}

- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   if (touch == self.firstTouch) {
      // first touch ended so remove both touches
      self.firstTouch = nil;
      self.secondTouch = nil;
   }
   else if (touch == self.secondTouch) {
      // second touch ended so remove touch only
      self.secondTouch = nil;
   }
}
```

Comment: To do my touch detection and storage I used a tutorial and modified it abit, but this has lost me :S. what do i do with UITouch* myTouch = [touch anyObject];
 CGPoint locationLeft = [myTouch locationInView: [myTouch view]];
 locationLeft = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:locationLeft];

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried iterating through the touches like this?

```
for (UITouch *touch in touches){
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    location = [self convertToNodeSpace:location];
```